# Infinite loop object creation

Tags: vb.net, object

I've created an object which is used over several methods so it needs to be declared at class level. But the object is an object of that class. So run and infinite loop? How can I get around this?

```
Public Class Reader
Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
Dim reador1 As reader = New Reader
Private Sub btnFileLocator1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFileLocator.Click
```

Comment: It's probably some code in the class constructor. Can you share that code?

Comment: Sorry thought it was probably something obvious I was doing wrong. According to the debug it goes into that and then just goes backwards and forwards between the first two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, using a `Shared` (static) reference to the class may solve your problems.

```
Public Class Cls
    Protected Shared _instance As New Cls

End Class
```

It is shared by all instances of the class (including itself) so it's only constructed once.